# The connection was reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have a submit form which is besicaly designed to store some data to data base. the technique what i used for it is Entitiy Data Model. Code behind is well written and there is no any mistake(i think so.).

But when i press submit button of the form it goes ofline and show the message like:

> "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>     The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
>       moments.
>     If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
>       connection.
>     If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
>       that Firefox is permitted to access the Web."

why this is happening?
Any suggestion is heighly appriciated.

Thank You,
Ravindra

Comment: Any recent changes made to the DB or IIS configuration? Do a quick IIS reset anyway.

Comment: Yes i have made little changes in a table but i was updated that table in model browser.